# how to retrieve records which occurred more than twice in oracle? 

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have this table

```
create table student (
   stu_id int,
   s_name nvarchar(max),
   s_subject nvarchar(max),
)
```

and this as data

```
insert into student values(123,'pammy','English');
insert into student values(123,'pammy','Maths');
insert into student values(123,'pammy','Chemistry');
insert into student values(124,'watts','Biology');
insert into student values(125,'Tom','Physics');
insert into student values(125,'Tom','Computer';
insert into student values(125,'Tom','ED';
```

so i wanted to retrieve records which has occurred more than twice. my code is

```
select stu_id,s_Name 
from student 
group by stu_id,s_Name 
having count(stu_id) >2 ;
```

the result was perfect.

but when i want `s_subject` as well it says no rows selected. I dont know why.

```
select stu_id,s_Name,s_subject 
from student 
group by stu_id,s_Name,s_subject 
having count(stu_id) >2 ;
```

Comment: You want subject only in the select, right ? a duplication is only if stu_id,s_Name are duplicated, right ? if so, which subject do you want to get ? there are more than one ...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's because none of your students have more than one record per subject.

```
select stu_id,s_Name,s_subject 
from student 
group by stu_id,s_Name,s_subject 
having count(stu_id) >2 ;
```

This code asks for records that occur more than twice that have the same Student ID, name and subject. None of the records in your sample meet this.

If, however, what you actually want is the ID, name and subjects of any student that is taking more than two classes, this can accomplished quite easily.

Using a slightly modified version of your initial SQL as a filter, we get this:

```
select stu_id, name, subject
from student
where stu_id in (   select stu_id 
                    from student 
                    group by stu_id 
                    having count(stu_id) >2 );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually instead of using IN I was using subquery which returned more than 1 row.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are grouping by all column exists in table, it will generate unique rows(record with one frequency row).As you already selecting rows having more than 2, it will not have the records with frequency 2.
If you will do with count=1, you will get all rows with count=1,

```
select stu_id,s_Name,s_subject 
from student 
group by stu_id,s_Name,s_subject
having count(stu_id) =1 ;
```

The output will be:

```
stu_id      s_Name      s_subject
   ----------- -------------
123         pammy       Chemistry
123         pammy       English
123         pammy       Maths
124         watts       Biology
125         Tom         Computer
125         Tom         ED
125         Tom         Physics
```